# Extension or settings in Chrome that syncs settings and extensions?

Tags: google-chrome, sync, browser-addons

I use Chrome at home and the office, and I was wondering if there is an extension that will sync not just my Chrome settings and bookmarks, but also my extensions and their settings between computers I run Chrome on?

http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=469242bc0eb964d6&hl=en

Is a thread asking for support on it, but nobody mentions if there is an extension created for Chrome doing this, or if it was ever implemented.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google Chrome version 6 now supports this, although at the time of writing you will have to install an unstable development build if you aren't already on the "Dev" channel.

[Chrome channels](http://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/dev/getting-involved/dev-channel) has information about how to change channels. The "Dev" builds are normally quite stable, I've never personally had any problems with using them for day-to-day work.